# Inject values dynamically in JSON string

Tags: json, ruby

I want to inject values in a string dynamically, Below is my piece of code:

```
arg = [{:state=>"running",:instance_id=>"i-0e0082f20149e5df0"},
        {:state=>"running",:instance_id=>"i-0e0082f20149e5df0"}]
argv = ['{ "tray" : "0", "onebox" : "False", "args" : #{arg},"param" : []}']
options = JSON.parse(argv[0] || "{}", :symbolize_names => true)
```

The above code is showing JSON parse error. How can i inject the value of args dynamically? Any help?

Comment: It's because your string is single-quoted. Interpolation doesn't work there. Use double-quoted string for this (or another interpolation-capable syntax, so that you don't have to escape json's double quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Sergio interpolation doesn't work in single-quoted strings.

```
arg = [{:state=>"running",:instance_id=>"i-0e0082f20149e5df0"},
    {:state=>"running",:instance_id=>"i-0e0082f20149e5df0"}]
argv = [ '{ "tray" : "0", "onebox" : "False", "args" : ' + arg.to_json + ',"param" : []}' ]
options = JSON.parse(argv[0] || "{}", :symbolize_names => true)
```